# Destructuring object as parameter in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am following a tutorial on react, and I am sorry for this newbie question but I am wondering why do we need to deconstruct parameters in this line, when we fetch data from an api:

```
.then( ({results: items}) => this.setState({items}))

componentWillMount(){
    fetch( 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json' )
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( ({results: items}) => this.setState({items}))
}
```

What I am wondering is, why can't we just pass the result of `response.json()` as a normal parameter like this:

```
.then( (items) => this.setState({items}))
```

Comment: The return value of the callback within `.then( callback )` will become the input value for the following `.then( ... )`. In this case, the return value is `response.json()` which apparently returns an object `{results: items}`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the data structure of the reponse of that API, but assuming that that code is working, you "need" to destructure because the data object you're receving it's something like { results: items, .... }, but you don't want to do anything with the rest of the object.

Obviously, you don't need to do it like that in a strict way. You can do something  like this `result => this.setState({ items: result.items })`, but I think that you can agree with me that is a bit less compact.

In the end is a question of preferences, but I personally prefer how the code looks with the destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to destruct:

```
.then( res => this.setState({items: res.result }))
```

or:

```
.then( response => response.json().result )
.then( items => this.setState({items}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple if you take a look of the response you will se that has an structure like the following.

```
{
 count: 0,
 results: ...
 ...
}
```

As you can see it's an object that one of its properties is called **results**. In this particular case it seems you don't care about the other information you only want to grab the **results** which is an array. If you were to just pass the return value from the callback without **Destructuring** you will set your state to a whole new object.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step

```
fetch( 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json' )
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( ({results: items}) => this.setState({items}))
```

`fetch` returns a Promise that resolves into a Response object. `response.json()` returns a Promise that resolves into a JSON of the response body. Every time that you return a Promise on a `then()` it's passed down the chain, so you get it as an input on the next `then`. Finally, the JSON object that the response body contains it's probably of the form `{ results, ...}`. on the last fetch, the destructuring takes that JSON, extracts whatever the `results` key has inside and renames it to `items`, so you can reference it inside the callback as a variable called `items`.

Without destructuring, that last `then` would need to have this shape:

```
.then(responseBodyAsJSON => this.setState({items: responseBodyAsJSON.results }))
```